# Pipe awk and grep to save a particular field of a file

Tags: linux, shell, awk, grep

What I want to achieve:

- grep: extract lines with the contig number and length
- awk: remove "length:" from column 2
- sort: sort by length (in descending order)

Current code

```
grep "length:" test_reads.fa.contigs.vcake_output | awk -F:'{print $2}' |sort -g -r > contig.txt
```

Example content of `test_reads.fa.contigs.vcake_output`:

```
>Contig_11 length:42
ACTCTGAGTGATCTTGGCGTAATAGGCCTGCTTAATGATCGT
>Contig_0 length:99995
ATTTATGCCGTTGGCCACGAATTCAGAATCATATTA
```

Expected output

```
>Contig_0 99995
>Contig_11 42
```

Comment: `grep | awk` is an anti-pattern.  Just use `awk`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` + `sort` solution here.

```
awk -F'[: ]' '/^>/{print $1,$3}' Input_file | sort -nrk2
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, running `awk` program to read Input_file first, where setting field separator as `:` OR space and checking condition if line starts from `>` then printing its 1st and 2nd fields then sending its output(as a standard input) to `sort` command where sorting it from 2nd field to get required output.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a gnu-awk solution that does it all in a single command without invoking `sort`:

```sh
awk -F '[:[:blank:]]' '
$2 == "length" {arr[$1] = $3}
END {
   PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"
   for (i in arr)
      print i, arr[i]
}' file

>Contig_0 99995
>Contig_11 42
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this, combining grep and awk:

```sh
awk -F '[ :]' '$2 == "length" {print $1, $3}' file | sort ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

- if more than one row has the same length then additionally sort the 1st column using 'version' sort

Adding some additional lines to the sample input:

```
$ cat test_reads.fa.contigs.vcake_output
>Contig_0 length:99995
ATTTATGCCGTTGGCCACGAATTCAGAATCATATTA
>Contig_11 length:42
ACTCTGAGTGATCTTGGCGTAATAGGCCTGCTTAATGATCGT
>Contig_17 length:93
ACTCTGAGTGATCTTGGCGTAATAGGCCTGCTTAATGATCGT
>Contig_837 ignore-this-length:1000000
ACTCTGAGTGATCTTGGCGTAATAGGCCTGCTTAATGATCGT
>Contig_8 length:42
ACTCTGAGTGATCTTGGCGTAATAGGCCTGCTTAATGATCGT
```

One `sed/sort` idea:

```
$ sed -rn 's/(>[^ ]+) length:(.*)$/\1 \2/p' test_reads.fa.contigs.vcake_output | sort -k2,2nr -k1,1V
```

Where:

- `-En` - enable extended regex support and suppress normal printing of input data
- `(>[^ ])+)` - (1st capture group) - `>` followed by 1 or more non-space characters
- `length:` - space followed by `length:`
- `(.*)` - (2nd capture group) - 0 or more characters (following the colon)
- `$` - end of line
- `\1 \2/p` - print 1st capture group + `<space>` + 2nd capture group
- `-k2,2nr` - sort by 2nd (spaced-delimited) field in `r`everse `n`umeric order
- `-k1,1V` - sort by 1st (space-delimited) field in `V`ersion order

This generates:

```
>Contig_0 99995
>Contig_17 93
>Contig_8 42
>Contig_11 42
```